# How to find the long device model name in LineageOS/Android 10?

Tags: lineageos, tech-specs

If I search for "how to find model name on Android", I get a bunch of results like:

https://www.sony.co.in/electronics/support/articles/SX368101

> 2. Use the model name from Settings
>
>    Open your phone settings menu
>    Android 10
>    Tap Settings > About phone > Model

Sure, but when I look there in LineageOS 17.1, I see Model & Hardware / Model : SM-A320FL

How do I find that this is "Samsung Galaxy ... [what?]"?

Has it been like this always? That Android never writes out the full/long/marketing name of the device, but only model number?

---

EDIT: I'm aware I can look up in a search engine "SM-A320FL", but I'm not interested in that - I'm interested in finding the device long model name from the running Android, even if it does not have Internet connection

Comment: On my Pixel 3a, stock ROM, Android 12, the "Model" is showing "Pixel 3a". On my Nexus 5, Lineage OS 14.1 (Android 7.1.2), the "Device model" is showing "Nexus 5". In fact, both devices don't show the model number! Since the model name is configurable during the making of the ROM ([it's on `build.prop`](https://www.droidviews.com/change-android-device-model-name-on-marshmallow-and-nougat/)), possibly the ROM maintainer decided to use the model number instead since Samsung devices usually have many variants with the same model name.

Comment: Use any of those "system info" apps maybe